# SG500X-48 10GB port blinks then stops when fiber plugged in

Tags: cisco, fiber, cisco-small-business

Connecting two SG500X-48's through XG1 on both sides with fiber. When I plug in the connector, the link light blinks rapidly a couple times (varies) then stops and goes dark. No connection, interface status is down.

I've ran down the obvious so far. Fiber cable is good, and switches are in standalone mode.

I'm mainly curious why the link light blinks then stops? Does this indicate a specific issue? (auto-neg failure, etc.)

I've searched for what this means, if anything, and came up empty.

Thanks

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

XG1 and XG2 aren't native stacking ports by default.  Use XG3 (S1) or XG4 (S2) and I bet it'll stack.

Comment: This is right.  Stacking Option One (default option): Ports XG3/S1 and XG4/S2 are configured as stack ports [Quick Start Guide](http://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/csbms/Sx500/quick_start/en/500_Series_QSG_En.pdf)